# basic perl, command prompt question: how to enter the next command after returning "perl" accidentally

Tags: perl, cmd

this may sound incredibly naive and stupid,
i'm new to programming

in command prompt after returning perl alone without any command, i'm not able to enter the next command. i'm struck there

i mean C:\users\sam>perl

how do i get to 
"C:\users\sam>"  again
its very frustrating thanks

Comment: This is just the same question as if you had typed `less`, `cat`, `grep`, `sed` or any number of other commands without arguments.

Comment: @Ether => looks like the OP is on Windows though, so those might be just as foreign as `perl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (interrupt).

Or, on Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> ([EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)).

Or, on UNIX (including Linux and OS X), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (EOF), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (quit), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> followed by the [`kill %`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command.

Answer (score 5):

`perl` by itself will start the interpreter and then wait for the program to come in via [STDIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STDIN#Standard_input_.28stdin.29). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will interrupt the interpreter and it will then quit.

To enter a short program via STDIN at the command line that does the same as `perl -e 'print "hello, world"'` (on Windows flip the quotes around: `perl -e "print 'hello, world'"`):

```
> perl
print "hello, world!";
^D
hello, world!
>
```

`^D` is a notation for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> which signifies the end of the input stream. Be sure to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, since Perl uses line buffered input.

Comment: IIRC, `^D` doesn't work on Windows.  Instead, you must use `^Z` on a line alone.

Comment: @ephemient: Just tried it on my machine, `^D` works just fine.

Comment: Perl on Windows has a concession where it treats `^D` the same as what normally happens with `^Z` (EOF).

Answer (score 0):

Type `__END__` on a line of its own.

Or `BEGIN{exit}`